# php DISTINCT - help how to write properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to use DISTINCT in a PHP line, but i really can't figure out how to write it properly..

I am having  this following sentence:

```
$udtag_traad = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT FROM portalen_traad WHERE bruger = '$username' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
```

How would I use DISTINCT in this line?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT what ?....

Comment: Write DISTINCT followed by your column name that you want to be distinct.

Comment: You have written `DISTINCT` properly. Was that the question?

Comment: @Bart he missed to choose column for distinct

Comment: I added SQL and MySQL tags to this question as `distinct` is a part of SQL, not PHP.

Comment: @user1844933 I was just joking around since the question is *"help how to write properly"*.

Answer (score 2):

The `distinct` statement in a query needs columns to pick:

```
select distinct
    col1
from
    yourTable
```

Will return only distinct values of `col1` from your table.

You can however select more than one column with it:

```
select distinct
    col1,
    col2
from
    yourTable
```

which will now return all the distinct combinations of `col1` and `col2`.